# What does 'infinite' mean in MS Access query

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, jet

[image]I am trying to re-make some Access queries using SSMS.  I ran across the below statement and I am a bit confused.  it uses the term 'infinite' and I have never seen that in Access.  Any help?

Code:

```
Bal: IIf([Infinite]<1,0,[infinite])
```

Comment: it appears to be the name of a column in a table. It's difficult to tell, though, because you've provided one single line of code entirely out of context, with no additional information. See [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: I agree - that is how I would name a column if I were using Access...but it never references an actual table...from my point of view this is non-functioning and I wanted to see if that was what others say.  I can add a screenshot of the query in design view if that is helpful...I am not an Access person - I am trying to decide what this would mean in SSMS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's referring to a field in the database named "Infinite" (or "infinite").

What it's *trying* to do is return 0 if [Infinite] is less than 1, and return the actual value if it's not less than 1.

However if your SQL Server is set to case sensitive collation, the statement will fail because `Infinite` <> `infinite`